# How to load images in background thread without affecting the UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am fetching a number of images from the internet and loading into my winform. Everything works fine except for the time lag when the images are fetched from a slow connection. I want the images to be fetched in background but the UI should not become unresponsive.

I tried ['BackgroundWorker'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206982/how-to-preload-images-in-a-background-thread) but it didn't work. Is there any other way of doing this? I read about async calls but I am not sure if it will work for me.

**Background Worker ::**

```
 foreach(String str in images )
            {
              BackgroundWorker bw=new BackgroundWorker();
              bw.DoWork += (s, e) => { run(str); };  // 
              bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

and `run()` simply sets the image url to the picture box.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: seems you tried to post a image. Did you?

Comment: @Shai The UI does not response when the images are loaded in the BackgroundWorker

Comment: Please add the BackgroungWorker code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make UI updates except from the thread you created the UI object on.

You can however use ["Invoke"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to make a call on the class's main thread.

```
Invoke( (Action)(() => { pictureBox.image = loadedImage; }) );
```